kalman filter for imu
i am trying to use a kalman filter in order to implement an IMU.
I am looking for help to tell me if the mistake(s) comes from my matrix or the way i compute every thing.
My situation is the following:
We don't care about the gravity and air friction.
At the begining, i have my initale position and an initiale speed
i receive data from:

an acceleromter (m/s2) on 3 axis (x, y, z)
a gyroscope (in euler angles)
a gps (every 3 sesondes)
The goal is to compute the position at anytime thanks to the filter.
i am using the library filterpy from python.

I have few results but i should be able to be precise enought for 400 000 sensors data but i only reach 8000 (for a certain trajectory).
Here are the matrix:
#state matrix
    F = np.array([
        [1, 0, 0, dt, 0 , 0 ],
        [0, 1, 0, 0 , dt, 0 ],
        [0, 0, 1, 0 , 0 , dt],
        [0, 0, 0, 1 , 0 , 0 ],
        [0, 0, 0, 0 , 1 , 0 ],
        [0, 0, 0, 0 , 0 , 1 ],
    ])
    
    #measurement matrix
    H = np.array([  
                    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
                ])
    
    # control matrix
    B =  np.array([ 
                    [(dt**2) / 2, 0          , 0          ],
                    [0          , (dt**2) / 2, 0          ],
                    [0          , 0          , (dt**2) / 2],
                    [dt         , 0          , 0          ],
                    [0          , dt         , 0          ],
                    [0          , 0          , dt         ]
                ])

    σ_acc = 10**-3
    σ_gyr = 10**-2
    var = 1 / (1/(σ_acc**2) + 1/(σ_gyr**2))
    # process noise matrix
    Q = Q_discrete_white_noise(dim=2, dt=dt, var=var, block_size=3)

    σ_gps = 10**-1
    # measurement uncertainty
    R = np.array([  
                    [σ_gps**2, 0       , 0       ],
                    [0       , σ_gps**2, 0       ],
                    [0       , 0       , σ_gps**2]
                ])
    
    return create_kalman_filter(6, 3, F=F, H=H, Q=Q, R=R, B=B)

Now you'll notice that i use only the accelation in my control matrix because i use the gyroscope data to set the acceleration in the global referencial like this:
    ψ, θ, φ = predict.direction[-1].ψ, predict.direction[-1].θ, predict.direction[-1].φ    
    # Rotation matrix
    R = np.array([  [np.cos(θ) * np.cos(ψ), np.sin(φ)*np.sin(θ)*np.cos(ψ)-np.cos(φ)*np.sin(ψ), np.cos(φ)*np.sin(θ)*np.cos(ψ)+np.sin(φ)*np.sin(ψ)],
                    [np.cos(θ) * np.sin(ψ), np.sin(φ)*np.sin(θ)*np.sin(ψ)+np.cos(φ)*np.cos(ψ), np.cos(φ)*np.sin(θ)*np.sin(ψ)-np.sin(φ)*np.cos(ψ)],
                    [-np.sin(θ)           , np.sin(φ)*np.cos(θ)                              , np.cos(φ)*np.cos(θ)                              ]
                ])

    acc_local = predict.acceleration[-1].to_nparray()
    acc_global = np.dot(R, acc_local)

    f.predict(u=acc_global)

And to finish, i only call f.update() when i have a gps position (with f being the instance of the kalman filter):
    if gps.is_notinitialized() == False:
        f.update(gps.to_nparray())

Does Anyone could tell me if i did a mistake in my reasonning? or is it from my matrixs?
don't hesitate to ask me further precisions if needed

A gyroscope, by itself, does not know absolute angles.  Where are you getting your absolute angles?
